# Image texture problem

Tags: texturing

[image][image]

I want to create an underground hallway. I added a cube in an empty world, resized it along the Y axis, downloaded concrete textures and put them in nodes.
But the texture looks stretched.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you don't give enough informations like how does your object looks like, is your unwrap correct, and the picture is hard to read, maybe share the object with its images packed?

Comment: I just added a cube in an empty world, resized it along the Y axis, downloaded concrete textures and put them in nodes.

Comment: could you please share your file with the images packed? It would really help  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texture is distorted, because you scaled your mesh, and you're not using a UV map.

**1) Apply object scale**
Because you scaled your object, your scale is probably messed up.
Just go to *Object->Apply->Scale*
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>

*Apply scale*
[image]

**2) UV unwrap your mesh**
You need to UV unwrap your mesh, so the texture is properly positioned.
In *Edit mode*, select all through  *Select->All*
and then go to *UV->Smart UV project*

*Unwrap your mesh*
[image]

**3) Connect your UV map**

Add a *Texture Coordinate* node, and use the UV output.
Add a *Mapping node*, to control the scale and position of your texture.

*Connect your nodes as in this image*
[image]

Done.